# Very slow presentation of the UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uialertcontroller

One thing that struck me recently has been how slow the UIAlertController is when it comes to presenting a lot of elements in it.

My `for` loop iterates over 400+ elements. I checked, and the loop takes a fraction of a second, but the presentation of the `UIAlertController` takes more than 16 seconds !!

I attach the Time Profiler output to support what I wrote.
Question is - is there any way to improve the speed of this component, or is there any substitute (custom library) for UIAlertController, that is better performance wise?

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

    for item in items {
      let button = UIAlertAction(title: item.title, style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in
            //  alert action
        })
        menuValueSelectionController.addAction(button)
    }


    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let popoverController = menuValueSelectionController.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.sourceView = sender
            popoverController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
        }

        menuValueSelectionController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.present(menuValueSelectionController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image: time profiler output]

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that `UIAlertController.addAction()` is not thread-safe. The UIAlertAction initializer might not be either.

Calling UIKit methods that aren't thread-safe from the background is a common cause of long pauses before a UI change takes effect. I suggest getting rid of the `DispatchQueue.global().async` wrapper. I'm betting the lag will go down dramatically.

That said, 400 alert actions seems like way too many to try to put into an alert controller. You might need to find another approach.

Comment: I checked that and it seems that you can safely use `UIAlertController.addAction()` in the background. The whole idea of wrapping it in `DispatchQueue.global().async` came from very slow presentation time of the `UIAlertController` :) You definitely are right about going with another approach - The documentation seems to lack this information, but one should avoid using `UIAlertController` when dealing with huge amount of data.

Comment: @DuncanC Just tried the same code on the main thread and it took 19 seconds for 400 actions.

Comment: So I guess you need to create a custom modal view controller with a table view in it. Table views designed to handle large numbers of cells.

Comment: @Michael and what about somebody who has to use it. If I see such an AlertController, I decide to delete it from my device. I think, that this will never happen, Apple stuff will refuse it earlier. I am sorry to say that, but following UI design recommendations as prescribed by Apple seems to be a good idea.

Comment: @user3441734 I couldn't agree more. that view has been long gone. unfortunately the documentation seems to lack info about any limits which can lead to performance issues described here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `UIAlertController` is not designed for such a huge amount of actions. I guess it is not a `UITableView` inside, so `UIAlertController` has to lay out all those buttons at once, which takes so much time.

I would suggest implementing custom `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController` controller with `UITableView` inside and present it modally instead of `UIAlertController`

**Edit**

Just checked my assumption with UI debugger and realized I was wrong. It is indeed a `UITableView` inside:

[image: Action sheet]

Comment: Yes it definitely seems that `UIAlertController` is simply a UIScrollView. The reference claims that it inherits from `UIViewController`. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller but not much is known about the implementation details.

Comment: @Michael By the way, is it `actionSheet` or `alert`?

Comment: alexburtnik The `preferredStyle` is set to `actionSheet`. Sorry I should have mentioned it at the very beginning.

Comment: @Michael Hm, it is a UITableView with a label in each cell, as you can see

Comment: Alex, you're right, thank you for checking that. Then the reason for the slow performance remains unknown.

Comment: It might be setting up a static table view with all the cells created at once. A custom modal with a table view using a normal data source should solve the problem. Set up the model to have an array of structs including action titles and the closures that you were setting up as your action handlers. That should be plenty fast.